# units of neural network layer are independent?

Tags: neural-network, correlation, covariance

In neural network, there are 3 main parts defined as input layer, hidden layer and output layer. Is there any correlation between units of hidden layer? For example, for 1st and 2nd neurons of hidden layer are independent of each other, or there is a relation between each other? Is there any source that explains this issue?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer depends on many factors. From probabilistic perspective they are independent **given inputs** and **before training**. If input is not fixed then they are heavily correlated (as two "almost linear" functions of the same input signal). Finally, after training they will be strongly correlated, and exact correlations will depend on initialisation and training itself.